# BDD in Pydev with Python in eclipse

Tags: python, bdd, pydev

We are trying to do BDD with Python using eclipse. We have installed pydev in eclipse but we are not going anywhere in integrating the BDD framework with this. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering you use something as https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-bdd, you can just use pytest as the test runner inside PyDev (in the **preferences > PyDev > PyUni**t select the pytest runner as the runner to be used).

-- Note: in PyDev 5.6.0 you can even use "Save to ..." and save that setting in the project properties so that all PyDev users will have the proper runner configured in the project by default -- provided you commit the related files to your VCS.